# How to remove specific value of a particular key From a Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I Want to remove a specific Cache Value From a Particular Cache.

Example:

```
Cache.Insert("TestCacheKey", "111", null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High,null); 
Cache.Insert("TestCacheKey", "222", null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, null);
Cache.Insert("TestCacheKey", "333", null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, null);
```

So, I have some data added in cache associated with the key i.e., `TestCacheKey` as shown above. Now, I want to delete a specific value i.e "111" from that key i.e., `TestCacheKey`. After deleting that specific value and when I retrieve that cache key (`TestCacheKey`),  I should just get only the remaining two records with values "222" & "333" associated with that key.

**So, How can deleting a specific value from a cache be achieved.**

Comment: you could of checked the cache class signature.

Comment: could you plz post your code

Answer (score 1):

First Parameter for `Cache.Insert` method is Key. In your code your it seems that keys are same and values from `Cache` object can be access by key.
If I am not wrong then modify your code like this

```
Cache.Insert("111","TestCacheKey",  null,DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60),Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,CacheItemPriority.High,null); 
Cache.Insert("222","TestCacheKey" , null,DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60),Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, null);
Cache.Insert("333","TestCacheKey",  null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60),Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, null);
```

For remove

`Cache.remove("111")`

Comment: if i have 10 records in cache and some condition i delete or add in that cache.

Comment: For single key there can be only one value.provide more information

Comment: @MiteshMachhi please add more to your last comment... its like you stopped short with explaining. So you delete or add... now? you delete or add by key. key has to be unique. What are you trying to do witch is different?

Comment: is it that you want to keep the key but change the value? then remove by key and add again with new value.

Comment: E.g If i have 10 Student Data on Page Load which get from Cache and bind grid using that cache. When I Delete one record from Grid then i just delete from only that particular data from cache not delete entire cache